# GeoLocation query in mongo db

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, geolocation, mongodb-query, mongoid

How Could i get longitude and lattitude using mongodb query from mongo collection 
based on disatnce and certain coordinates.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a559b13ae201d0c05cb6f6a"),
    "id" : "99623",
    "city" : "Wasilla",
    "cnty" : "Matanuska Susitna",
    "cntyFips" : null,
    "st" : "AK",
    "stName" : "Alaska",
    "areaCode" : "907",
    "lat" : 61.5816,
    "long" : -149.4393,
    "rgn" : "West",
    "__v" : 0 
}
```

in this document "lat" is for latitude and "long" is for longitude.

so basically i have to get all ids based on present id lat and long which comes in a particular miles distance range.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need a little more information on the structure of the documents that you are querying, but here is a simple example of the query available in the Mongo documentation [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/nearSphere/).
It's worth noting that you require a 2dsphere index for location data defined as GeoJSON points in order for this to be effective.

```
 {
   $nearSphere: {
      $geometry: {
         type : "Point",
         coordinates : [ <longitude>, <latitude> ]
      },
      $minDistance: <distance in meters>,
      $maxDistance: <distance in meters>
   }
 }
```

Comment: i have a document which contains latitude and longitude and id as zipcode.
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a559b13ae201d0c05cb6f6a"),
    "id" : "99623",
    "city" : "Wasilla",
    "cnty" : "Matanuska Susitna",
    "cntyFips" : null,
    "st" : "AK",
    "stName" : "Alaska",
    "areaCode" : "907",
    "lat" : 61.5816,
    "long" : -149.4393,
    "rgn" : "West",
    "__v" : 0
}
in this document lat is for latitude and long is for longitude.

so basically i have to get all ids based on present id lat and long which comes in a particular miles distance range.

Comment: Is it possible to update the structure of your data or are you locked into the format? You could write a complex query that could get the information but it would be best and fastest to get your data coordinates into a GeoJSON format.

Comment: thnx @Genthe 
i managed my document structure in GeoJSON format .

Comment: So it's all working for you now or do you still need assistance?

Comment: That's great. Glad you are sorted.

Answer (score 1):

Mongo supports [GeoJSON](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/geojson/) which should allow you to perform basic queries easily on these kind of data. Examples include [`$geoWithin`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/geoWithin/#op._S_geoWithin) for your particular use-case.